# Como recorrer toda la informacion devuelta de un observable y mostrarla en un select tag de html ANGULAR?

Tags: angular, observable

Este es mi codigo `http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').subscribe((data) => { console.log(data); });` logro obtener toda la informacion del endpoint de esta manera [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero recorrer toda la informacion pero solo introducir el nombre de cada pais en un select, pero no se como recorrer el objeto, he intentado guardar la informacion en un array lo logro hacer pero no lo logro iterar, por ejem: quiero recorrer data['iterar'].name al poner un numero en 'iterar' logro mostrar solo el pais pero quiero iterar por todos los paises, alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para mostrar los datos en el select puedes llenarlo con un `ngFor` luego de crear un arreglo con los nombres de los paises.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      
          <select>
            <option>Seleccione</option>
            <option *ngFor="let pais of paises" value="{{pais}}">{{pais}}</option>
    
          </select>
      
      `,
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
    
    
      paises : any = [];
    
      constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    
      this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all').subscribe((data : any) => { 
    
        // usar el método map para crear un nuevo arreglo con los nombres de los 
        // paises
        this.paises = data.map(p => p.name);
      
      
      });
    
    
      }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo me funciono :), tengo una duda, ya antes habia intentado con esta solucion, pero lo estaba probando en un console.log antes, y el consol.log no me muestra nada estoy haciendo esto for (let p of this.paises) {
      console.log(p);
    } sabes por que en el consol.log no me funciona y en todo lo demas si? Soy nuevo en Stack overflow y javascript :)

Comment: Quizás no lo estabas usando en el lugar correcto. Si quieres puedes agregar ese código a la pregunta para revisarlo.